# Import chinese character in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, excel, ems

how can i import excel file with chinese character in to mysql table(EMS Manager).
can anyone please appreciatively help me ?
Thanks.

Comment: all English characters are successfully imported but Chinese char are corrupted and display question mark(?) in mysqltable. With the help of import wizard of EMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is the problem to import the data or the only chinese characters ??

Check out:

1. http://www.sqlmanager.net/en/products/mysql/dataimport/download/5/2041
2. http://www.dbtube.org/cms/