# Import Chinese characters in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, html, encoding, ems

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Import chinese character in mysql table.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898088/import-chinese-character-in-mysql-table)

How can I import an Excel file with Chinese characters into a MySQL table (EMS Manager).
Can anyone please help me? Thanks.

Comment: If you're using UTF-8 (or some other Unicode encoding), it should work OK. Note that you should have UTF-8 in your PHP script, HTTP headers, MySQL connection, and MySQL tables - other setups are possible, but they increase the odds of a mix-up. Do you have a specific problem with the import? Please edit the *specific* problem you are having into your question (what works, what not, what you tried, etc.) - nobody can help you if your question essentially says "it's broken, halp". (btw, welcome to StackOverflow)

Comment: I'm guessing you couldn't find your original question which is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898088/import-chinese-character-in-mysql-table). I've closed this as a duplicate of your original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by default connection is not UTF-8 enabled in many installs, try this in my.cnf:

```
[client]
default-character-set = utf8

[mysqld]
collation_server=utf8_unicode_ci
character_set_server=utf8
skip-character-set-client-handshake
default-character-set = utf8
default-collation = utf8_general_ci
```

There is also a SQL way to do it in connection if above cannot be set:

```
SET NAMES UTF8
```